# deque.resize() from the *front*?

Tags: c++, deque

How do you `resize` a `std::deque` from the *front* instead of the back?

(Yes, of course I can `push_front` a dummy value thousands of times, but is there a better/more efficient way?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an overload of `insert` that inserts N elements:

```
std::deque<int> c;

std::size_t new_size = get_new_desired_size();

c.insert(c.begin(), new_size - c.size(), int());
```

(This example requires that `new_size >= c.size()`)

Comment: Why it is more efficient than making `new_size` times `push_front()`?

Comment: @RafałRawicki: It won't be less efficient, but if implementation is clever, it might be better (deque has random-access iterators, so you can get the count easily).

Comment: It may not be more efficient.  However, with this function, the library knows immediately how many elements will need to be added to the beginning of the sequence, so it may be able to optimize its allocations.

Comment: @iCE-9:  If `new_size - c.size()` yields a negative result, it will wrap (according to the rules of unsigned arithmetic) and yield a (likely humongous) positive number.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: exactly, they're unsigned.

Comment: @iCE-9: `insert` makes it pretty obvious this is a method of extending the deque, not shortening it.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: the question was rhetorical, pointing at the fact that the solution could be (and was) improved by checking that a humongous amount of elements are not inserted where the target size is actually smaller.

Answer (score 1):

A more complete solution:

```
std::deque<T> deque;
std::size_t new_size = /* ... */;
if (new_size >= deque.size())
    deque.insert(deque.begin(), new_size - deque.size(), T());
else
    deque.erase(deque.begin(), deque.begin() + deque.size() - new_size);
```

Due to the nature of `std::deque`, all *remaining* iterators should remain valid in either case.